# JAVA open folder in other drive using SFTP hosted in Windows and download files

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

the code follows:

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();

String user = username;
String host = host;
int port = 22;
String privateKey = privateKeyPath;

jsch.addIdentity(privateKey);

Session sessionJ = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);

java.util.Properties configJ = new java.util.Properties();
configJ.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
sessionJ.setConfig(configJ);

sessionJ.connect();

Channel channel = sessionJ.openChannel("sftp");            

channel.connect();              

ChannelSftp cs = (ChannelSftp) channel;            
out.print(cs.ls("D:/MyPath/mySubFolder"));               
cs.exit(); 
channel.disconnect();
```

That's what i get:

```
3: Permission denied, file: /D:/myPath/mySubFolder at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2833) at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:2185) at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:2202) at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.ls(ChannelSftp.java:1566) at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.ls(ChannelSftp.java:1527) at org.apache.jsp.includes.shop.hubs.infinitiumSFTPConnection_jsp._jspService(infinitiumSFTPConnection_jsp.java:214) at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377) at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313) at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) at CharsetFilter.doFilter(CharsetFilter.java:39) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

That's because jsch ls expects relative path.
If i connect to the sftp using the console I am prompted in C:\Users\user
How can I move to D: and than to the correct path?
The goal will be download files stored in D:/myPath/mySubFolder

thanks for help

EDIT:

At the moment the only way was change the starting folder after the SFTP connection to the D: volume.

Comment: Have you tried a simple `cs.cd("path")`. The doc says you can specify the path as a directory path, absolute or relative to the current remote path

Comment: I get the same :( with cs.cd("D:/OCSBProjects/RPSEPAPER"); and out.print(cs.ls("."));

Answer (score 0):

for me (I am using jsch 0.1.54) worked add "/" before drive, so the path should looks like:

```
out.print(cs.ls("/D:/MyPath/mySubFolder"));
```

Hope it helps.